# Timer Background transition

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, background-image

I was trying to have my Form's background change when I press a button with a transition.

I figured the most simple and fast way to do this would be to put a white panel over my Form, with a blank backcolor, and to change its alpha component from 0 to 250 then from 250 to 0 when I click the button. 
When alpha reaches its maximum value, I want to change the background image.
This technique worked like an hour ago, but now the color does not change at all, and my code is not entirely executed. 
Here's the function that is called by the Timer :

```
private void ChangeIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    if (progressBar.Value == progressBar.Maximum-progressBar.Step)
    {
        t.Stop();

        btnDébut.Enabled = true;
        btnFin.Enabled = true;
        btnPrécédent.Enabled = true;
        btnSuivant.Enabled = true;

        if (indiceCourant >= dt.Rows.Count)
        {
            this.indiceCourant = 0;
        }

        lblChargement.Visible = false;
        progressBar.Visible = false;
        RemplitChamps(indiceCourant);
    }

    progressBar.Step = 10;
    progressBar.Maximum = 200;
    progressBar.PerformStep();

    MessageBox.Show(progressBar.Value.ToString() + " " + pnlFondEcran.BackColor.A.ToString() + " " + progressBar.Maximum.ToString());

    if(progressBar.Value <100)
    {
        this.pnlFondEcran.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(pnlFondEcran.BackColor.A + progressBar.Maximum/progressBar.Step,255, 255,255);
        // i wanna add 24 each time, until alpha=240
    }             
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
        this.pnlFondEcran.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(pnlFondEcran.BackColor.A -progressBar.Maximum / progressBar.Step, 255, 255, 255);
        //then substract 24 each time
    }
}
```

The Panel's name is pnlFondEcran.
The progressbar works  fine.
The `MessageBox.Show(some stuff )`'s ouptpur is 0,20,40... to 200, 0, 200.
The `progressBar.Value<100` statement is never evaluated until the first last time the function is called, I have no idea why.

Here's the method calling ChangeIndex() :

```
private void DebutTimer()//lance le timer pour la progressbar
{
    lblChargement.Visible = true;
    progressBar.Visible = true;

    progressBar.Value = 0;
    //gestion du timer
    t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    t.Interval = 150;
    t.Enabled = true;
    t.Tick += new EventHandler(ChangeIndex);
    t.Start();
    //gestion des boutons
    btnDébut.Enabled = false;
    btnFin.Enabled = false;
    btnPrécédent.Enabled = false;
    btnSuivant.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: First thought would be issues relating to updating the GUI on a non-GUI thread, although that typically will throw. Are you handling multiple threads in this app?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What's your specific problem, again?

Comment: I'd concur with @DavidW. What is calling `ChangeIndex()`?

Comment: I'm editing my post to answer this :)

Comment: And the form this piece of code belongs to is not my app's main form, so there's an other one running in the background

Comment: Is your timer started on the same thread as the UI? `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`s do not work on a thread besides the UI one.

Comment: it is indeed declared in the active form's class :         System.Windows.Forms.Timer t;

Comment: Sorry let me clarify, is the timer started on the UI thread? You see all the button's get disabled as you would expect?

Comment: Yes, I do. Seems like everything works fine except this if part